# Masking in Infragistics XamGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, infragistics, xamgrid

We are working on WPF application using MVVM architecture and Infragistics controls. The main form displays Infragistics XamGrid which is bound to a DataTable. The DataTable has columns with Double data type. I want to set masking for these columns in xaml. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

For the following class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how you implement a mask in the XamGrid

```
    <ig:XamGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3">
        <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
            <ig:TextColumn Key="Name"  />
            <ig:TemplateColumn 
                HeaderText="Salary" Key="Salary" >
                <ig:TemplateColumn.EditorTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ig:XamMaskedInput Value="{Binding Path=Salary, Mode=TwoWay}" Mask="{}{double:10.7}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ig:TemplateColumn.EditorTemplate>
            </ig:TemplateColumn>
        </ig:XamGrid.Columns>

        <ig:XamGrid.EditingSettings>
            <ig:EditingSettings AllowEditing="Row" IsMouseActionEditingEnabled="DoubleClick" />
        </ig:XamGrid.EditingSettings>
    </ig:XamGrid>
```